# is there a way to check if a specific template object is ready?

Tags: meteor

Im trying to call subscribe using the Template.list.my_playlist_id variable, as so:

```
Meteor.subscribe("links", Template.list.my_playlist_id);
```

The problem is, i need to make sure that the my_playlist_id exists before i use it to subscribe, Is there an event that I can wait for like Template.list.my_playlist_id.ready?

thanks

Comment: Where do you set Template.list.my_playlist_id?

Comment: I set in in Meteor.call, in the callback function. the call function gets called once during Meteor.startup, but I would like to subscribe at different points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you would want to use the template variable itself, but rather use what it is set from in turn. If I understand your context correctly, something like this might be what you are after:

```
Template.list.my_playlist_id = function() {
    Session.get('my_playlist_id');
};

Session.setDefault('my_playlist_id', null);
Meteor.startup(function() {
    Meteor.call('getplaylist', function(err, res) {
        Session.set('my_playlist_id', res);
    });

    Deps.autorun(function() {
        if (Session.get('my_playlist_id') != null) {
            Meteor.subscribe("links", Session.get('my_playlist_id'));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: quick question, when does Deps.autorun function gt called?